# Failed to open VScode within Samba Share

Tags: ubuntu, visual-studio-code, samba, cifs

In my Ubuntu system: Linux aldebaran 5.8.0-50-generic #56~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Mon Apr 12 21:46:35 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Normally I go to the directory where the C++ source is located and start VS Code with

```
user-prompt> code .
```

On locally stored projects this works fine.
But not within a mounted cifs volume from my NAS. I immediately get:

```
cannot stat path of the current working directory: Permission denied
```

The directory is perfectly readable or writable by all other commands and bash scripts, but only VS Code has problems.

Starting with "sudo" make no difference. Same error.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is probably because you installed a snap version of vscode.

uninstall vscode with :

```
sudo snap remove code
```

and try installing it with the deb package on https://code.visualstudio.com/
using :

```
sudo apt install ./VS_CODE_FILENAME.deb
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
code \\YOUR_SERVER_IP\Folder_Name
```

or

open vscode -> file -> open folder -> \\YOUR_SERVER_IP\Folder_Name

Refer to the image reference.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kWhLH.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K3i6u.png)

Comment: Why should this work ? And the other way around not ? I will try tomorrow, but even if it runs this way it leaves questions.

Comment: Using the full path from \\servername\path\to\mount seems to work for me. The network mount (V:\ for me) was giving me "file is a directory". This seems like a bug in either windows or VSCode because I would expect these to work exactly the same but... it worked for me.

Comment: Further update: this still has bugs when trying to rename a file it's complaining about being unable to create the parent directory (which... it doesn't need to do I'm just trying to rename the child file) so I'm abandoning trying to use VSCode with samba.

Comment: Did you run it with administrator privileges?
Have you ever created a folder in File Explorer after connecting to Samba?
Did you log in to the root account and proceed with the Samba ID/password?
I think the remote area lacks authority.